# i'm using a file to store payment details.. And i'm using fs module to make changes in it. It's working in local server but not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs

this is the api->

```
router.patch('/admin/changePayment', (req, res) => {
const paymentPath=path.join(__dirname,'../../'); 
const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
const validUpdates=['upiId','merchant','onlinePayment'];
const isValidOperation=updates.every((update)=>{
    return validUpdates.includes(update);
    })
if (!isValidOperation)
    return res.status(400).send({ error: 'Invalid Updates' });
try {

    let dataJSON=fs.readFileSync(paymentPath+'/payment.json').toString();
    const obj = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
    console.log(obj)

    
    updates.forEach((update)=>{
        obj[update]=req.body[update]
    });

    console.log(obj);
    dataJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
    fs.writeFileSync(paymentPath+'/payment.json',dataJSON);
    res.send();
} catch (error)
{
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({ error });
}
```

})
It's working in the local server so I also checked the logs in the heroku logs and the logs were->

```
{ upiId: 'bhanesh@upi', merchant: 'Paytm', onlinePayment: true }
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233313+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233314+00:00 app[web.1]: upiId: {
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233315+00:00 app[web.1]: jQuery341052852592744232531: { events: [Object], blur: false, focus: false }
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233315+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233316+00:00 app[web.1]: merchant: {
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233316+00:00 app[web.1]: jQuery341052852592744232531: { events: [Object], blur: false, focus: false }
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233316+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233317+00:00 app[web.1]: onlinePayment: true
2021-08-01T09:18:10.233317+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

How to fix this, or suggest a methods to store payment details?????

Comment: Does this path `path.join(__dirname,'../../'` exist on remove server ?

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri yes it is on the deployment server(Heroku) also

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? And btw. you should not use `fs.readFileSync` or `fs.writeFileSync` on the server, because it's a blocking call ...

Comment: write file sync is not working. Then what to use to store payment detail on which customers can pay @derpirscher

Comment: "is not working" is not a valid error description. How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @derpirscher when I'm checking in the payment.json file after changing the UPI or merchant name it's  not changing

Comment: I'm not really familiar with heroku, but the chances that `fs.writeFileSync()` just "doesn't work" without throwing any error are quite low. Are you sure, you are inspecting the correct file? Are you sure there are no errors thrown? Instead of the `...Sync` methods, you shoud use `fs.writeFile` and `fs.readFile` which are async and therefore non-blocking.